# Integrate Firebase web chat seamlessly with an existing application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to integrate Firebase web chat in an existing web application. The integration has to be seamless . I would not like to store the username and password of a user in the Firestore database. Can this be done? If yes, then how?

Comment: Firebase can be used to build chat applications for sure. This question is way too broad to answer on Stack Overflow. I recommend reading a few tutorials, and giving it a spin. For a good starting point, see https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/

Comment: My exact question is that can i host Firestore in my own server as I do not wish to expose the user credentials to a third party.

Comment: All Firebase products are fully hosted services. While some of them have local emulators, they can currently not be run locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Firebase products are fully hosted services. While some of them have local emulators, they can currently not be run locally to receive traffic from published apps.